# iOS Safari’s experimental HTTP/3 support can’t works well with Google

Tags: html, ios, web, safari

When HTTP/3 enabled in Safari’s experimental feature, it have some wrong with Google.

When I need to enter password again (like attempt to change password), it will redirect to accounts.google.com/CheckCookie and show “moved temporarily”, reCAPTCHA can’t work too. RequestIdleCallback will broke all Google Login and freezed after password entered.